# How do I combine two independent Cmake projects?

Tags: c, azure, cmake, azure-iot-sdk

So I've two projects [Azure C++ IOT SDK](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c)(used to send robot data like joint angles and positions to IotHub) and [libfranka](https://github.com/frankaemika/libfranka)(used to interact with the robotic arm).

The purpose is to send real-time data or telemetry from the robotic arm to my IoTHub.

My attempt at combining two projects:

1. Added libfranka as a subdirectory to the toplevel [CMAkeLists.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/main/CMakeLists.txt) file of azure-iot-sdk and used this command to compile the azure-iot-sdk

```
cmake -Bcmake -Duse_prov_client=ON -Dhsm_type_symm_key=ON -Drun_e2e_tests=OFF
```

Got this error

```
CMake Error at libfranka/test/CMakeLists.txt:10 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    SetupGoogleTest


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

gtest is already installed on my linux machine.

2. Next I successfully compiled and installed libfranka(using the commands below) to use its header files in the azure-iot-sdk but it didn't work as well.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DBUILD_TESTS=OFF ..
cmake --build .
sudo make install
```

I know that using

```
add_subdirectory(libfranka)
```

is not sufficient to add libfranka to the azure-iot-sdk.

Is there a simple way to combine these two projects?

Comment: @LeelaRajesh_Sayana could you provide any suggestion?